# Fetching value from DOM after Ajax/jQuery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, dom

I'm new member here, and I was looking around for a solution of my problem which is like following:

I have an element tag which is loaded into the DOM after an ajax/jQuery post which is defined like this:

```
  function PostAndUpdate(_username) {
        $.post("/SearchCompetitor/Index", { username: _username }, StartLoading())
                           .done(function (data) {
                               if (data !== "UsernameError") {
                                   StopLoading();
                                   var brands = $('<table />').append(data).find('#tableProducts').html();
                                   $('#tableProducts').html(brands);
                                   var header = $('<div />').append(data).find('.bs-glyphicons').html();
                                   $('.bs-glyphicons').html(header);
                                   $('#tableProducts thead, #header').fadeIn("slow");
                                   $('#emptyText').hide();


                               }
                               else {
                                   StopLoading();
                                   ShowMessage("Nouser was found under: " + $('.txtSearch').val());
                               }
                           })
                           .fail(function (data) {
                               StopLoading();
                               ShowMessage("Something went wrong, please try again!");
                           });
    }
```

Where the element looks like this:

```
<div class="count feedbackScoreClass" value="@ViewBag.FeedbackScore">@ViewBag.FeedbackScore</div>
```

And now I'm trying to fetch its value here in the next on button click to post it onto the server:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".btnSaveWatchlist", function () {
            StopLoading();

            if ($('#TextArea1').val() == "" || !$('#ratingSystem input').is(':checked')) {
                ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
                console.log($('.feedbackScoreClass').val());
                return;
            } else {
                $.post("/SearchCompetitor/SaveWatchList", { comment: $('#TextArea1').val(), rating: $('input[name=rating]:checked').val(), feedback: $('.feedbackScoreClass').val(), competitor: $('.txtSearch').val() })
                             .done(function (data) {
                                 if (data == "Ok") {

                                     var l = document.getElementById('cancelButton');
                                     l.click();
                                 } else if (data == "AllFieldsRequired") {
                                     ShowErrorMessage("All fields are required!");
                                     return;
                                 }
                             });
            }
        });
```

Where I try to fetch the elements value after being updated in DOM like this:

```
$('.feedbackScoreClass').val()
```

But this doesn't works, I jsut get an empty string... How could I fix it?

Comment: Any ideas guys? :)

Comment: You need to handle the events dynamically. Look for 'Dynamic Event Handling Jquery' here and you'll find a ton of answers. In short, you need to first have a static parent and then find your dynamic elements within it. There are tons and tons of answers here addressing this already.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit new to JQuery as well, but I made a quick research so hope that helps.

First of all in the jquery documentation, I saw this explanation

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty
>   collection, it returns undefined.

So when I checked your code, except for this one
 `<div class="count feedbackScoreClass" value="@ViewBag.FeedbackScore">@ViewBag.FeedbackScore</div>` 
all the elements you use `.val()` method is an input field (I made this assumption based on the class and id names, so correct me if I am wrong)

So since your element is a `<div>` it might be the reason that it returns an empty string with `.val()`.

When I searched for alternative ways, for the elements that are not an input field I've found the followings:

If you use `.val()` to get the value of the attribute value

```
<div class="count feedbackScoreClass" value="@ViewBag.FeedbackScore">
```

You can give `$('.feedbackScoreClass').attr('value')` a try instead

Or for the value of the html, you can use `.html()` method as well (you already use this method a couple of times in your code ).

However it is important to consider the following explanations about  .attr() and .html() that are

> In an HTML document, .html() can be used to get the contents of any
>   element. If the selector expression matches more than one element,
>   only the first match will have its HTML content returned.
>
> The .attr() method gets the attribute value for only the first element
>   in the matched set. To get the value for each element individually,
>   use a looping construct such as jQuery's .each() or .map() method.

So maybe you can also use an additional id tag in your element to make things more easier